# Magento Product Save Issues - Asymmetric Transaction Rollback

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.3.2

We have a Magento 2.3.2 CE instance running and it has been working for us for a while without issue. Recently our products stopped saving and instead starting throwing the `Asymmetric transaction rollback` error.

The only error being logged is the reference to the error line (Magento/Framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:324) without any further information.

I tried all the suggestions and fixes I could think of (or find online), including:

- Full Reindex (completed successfully)
- Cleared Cache (cache:flush, cache:clean)
- Manually removed `generated`,`var/page_cache`,`var/cache`
- Changed indexers to run on schedule rather than save
- Verified search engine (elasticsuite) is running
- Changed search engine to MySql
- Ran the `setup:upgrade` and `setup:static-content:deploy` commands

After I tried these things and none of them changed, or fixed the error delved into the Magento code. After adding some logging and following the error through the logic I determined the error is being thrown due to a transaction being rolled back multiple times.

I was able to get my products to save again by changing:

```
public function rollBack()
{
    if ($this->_transactionLevel === 1) {
        $this->logger->startTimer();
        parent::rollBack();
        $this->_isRolledBack = false;
        $this->logger->logStats(LoggerInterface::TYPE_TRANSACTION, 'ROLLBACK');
    } elseif ($this->_transactionLevel === 0) {
        throw new \Exception(AdapterInterface::ERROR_ASYMMETRIC_ROLLBACK_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        $this->_isRolledBack = true;
    }
    --$this->_transactionLevel;
    return $this;
}
```

to

```
public function rollBack()
{
    if ($this->_transactionLevel === 1) {
        $this->logger->startTimer();
        parent::rollBack();
        $this->_isRolledBack = false;
        $this->logger->logStats(LoggerInterface::TYPE_TRANSACTION, 'ROLLBACK');
    } elseif ($this->_transactionLevel === 0) {
        throw new \Exception(AdapterInterface::ERROR_ASYMMETRIC_ROLLBACK_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        //changed to false to allow products to save - NOT SURE OF SCOPE OF THIS CHANGE
        $this->_isRolledBack = false;
    }
    --$this->_transactionLevel;
    return $this;
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing the problem originally, why this change has seemed to fix the issue for now, and if there are any (negative) side effects of making the change?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working in the end? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: @fistameeny The change I mentioned at the end of my question is still in place on our instance, which did get rid of the issue. I'm still to this day not sure what caused the original issue, or what the ramifications of the change are but we haven't noticed any negative side effects (not to say there aren't any, just none that have been noticed).

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try seeing as nothing else is working! This is on a 2.4.3 instance for what it's worth, so still an issue in later versions

Comment: @fistameeny would love to here how it goes, and if it fixes the issue for you!

Comment: Your fix seems to work. I've possibly pinned down the issue to being that some maintenance was done on our MySQL server (possibly a version change, possibly config), but can't yet tell. It's a managed service, so hard to establish what has changed, but using a different database server with the "old" code works fine.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting, I'll have to dig through my old notes and see if we had made any changes to our DB leading up to the issue. I'll update you if I find anything of value!

Answer (score 0):

You should run this command to turn on the dev mode:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Then it will show the errors.